# Statistics from C++ source code

Tags: c++, statistics, development-environment, code-analysis

Do you know any type of tool, possibly for Linux and open source, that can be used to extract statistics from C/C++ source code files.

Apart from the number of lines, I would be interested in:

- number of comment lines
- number of classes used
- number of declarations

and so on.

Comment: I enjoy SourceMonitor (http://www.campwoodsw.com/sourcemonitor.html), has a variety of interesting metrics and breaks things down by file, class, and method. I think it's Windows-only, though.

Comment: http://www.osnews.com/images/comics/wtfm.jpg

Comment: unfortunately it works just on Windows...

Comment: @Alexander Tobias Heinrich   Aahah, I've just seen the image you linked, I agree with that!

Comment: Search the web for "C++ metrics".

Answer (score 8):

I use [CLOC](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/) (http://cloc.sourceforge.net/) for counting lines of code, blank lines and comments. However CLOC does not interpret the code and thus cannot count classes, declarations etc.

And one should probably mention that this kind of statistics is considered meaningless by most people...

Comment: Yes I know CLOC but I wanted a more complete tool.

Comment: I know that they can be meaningless for most people but having a way to measure your code could be useful for estimates and similar tasks IMHO

Comment: I agree, code statistics can be usefull for personal use. But anyone who reads this should know, that such statistics cannot be used to make code of different people comparable. A satement like "Programmer A writes 20 LOC/day and is therefore better than programmer B who writes 18 LOC/day" are ridiculous. And btw I don't know of any other tool than CLOC...